# Javascript + Firebase blog addpost function firstId returns undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a blog with Js and Firebase. When I add the posts to the firebase database the first one's Id is `undefined` then in starts increasing from `myid-0`. 
Here is my code:

```
<button onclick="writeUserData(document.getElementById('blog-title').value, document.getElementById('blog-content').value, uniqueId(uniqueId))">Add</button>
```

...........

```
function uniqueId(uniqueId) {
    var counter = 0;
    window.uniqueId = function(){
        return ('myid-' + counter++);
    }
}

function writeUserData(title, content, postID) {
    firebase.database().ref('posts/' + postID).set({
    title: title,
    content: content
    });
}
```

Why is it not starting to add the post from myid-0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your function `uniqueId()` is not correct. You can see it by having a button in your page with the following code:

```
<input
  id="clickMe"
  type="button"
  value="clickme"
  onclick="console.log(uniqueId());"
/>
```

So if you change your function to something like the following it will work:

```
var counter = 0;
function uniqueId() {
  return 'myid-' + counter++;
}

function writeUserData(title, content, postID) {
    firebase.database().ref('posts/' + postID).set({
    title: title,
    content: content
    });
}
```

......

```
<button onclick="writeUserData(document.getElementById('blog-title').value, document.getElementById('blog-content').value, uniqueId())">Add</button>
```

---

Note however that you can let Firebase generating the UniqueIds, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push

Comment: You are welcome. Note that you can let Firebase generating the Unique Ids, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push